# How do I log HTTP requests/responses in Netty 4.0.0.Beta1?

Tags: netty

Using Netty 4.0.0.Beta1, what would be the best way for me to log the incoming/outgoing HTTP traffic to a netty-based server? My pipeline is currently:

```
p.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
p.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(1048576));

p.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
p.addLast("handler", new MyBusinessLogicHandler());
```

I tried writing a handler that implements `ChannelInboundMessageHandler<FullHttpRequest>`, and then does the logging in the `inboundBufferUpdated(ChannelHandlerContext ctx)` method, which seems to work fine for incoming requests, but is that the recommended way?

When I tried to implement `ChannelOutboundMessageHandler<FullHttpResponse>`, I wasn't successful in seeing the actual FullHttpResponse objects inside the `flush(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelPromise promise)` method.

Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: So I more or less figured out I had a simple issue with where I was placing my logging handlers. I am still implementing `ChannelInboundMessageHandler<FullHttpRequest>` & `ChannelOutboundMessageHandler<FullHttpResponse>`. Is this the best approach?

Comment: yes it is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Note: The Netty API has changed a lot since its beta days. Now you can just add a `LoggingHandler` in the pipeline.  `MessageLoggingHandler` and `ByteLoggingHandler` are gone.

You can put `MessageLoggingHandler` after the codec handlers in your pipeline (i.e before `MyBusinessLogicHandler`).  By default, it logs all messages and events at `DEBUG` level, so you might want to adjust that.  If you are rather interested in low-level traffic dump, please use `ByteLoggingHandler` and place it before the codec handlers.

Comment: What file should this config go into?  I'm using netty within the Playframework.  I don't know where to tell netty to create an HTTP access log.