# how to log Spring 5 WebClient call

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, spring-webflux

I'm trying to log a request using Spring 5 WebClient. Do you have any idea how could I achieve that?

(I'm using Spring 5 and Spring boot 2)

The code looks like this at the moment:

```
try {
    return webClient.get().uri(url, urlParams).exchange().flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(Test.class))
            .map(test -> xxx.set(test));
} catch (RestClientException e) {
    log.error("Cannot get counter from opus", e);
    throw e;
}
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can easily do it using [ExchangeFilterFunction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFilterFunction.html)

Just add the custom `logRequest` filter when you create your `WebClient` using `WebClient.Builder`.

Here is the example of such filter and how to add it to the `WebClient`.

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
public class MyClient {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    // Create WebClient instance using builder.
    // If you use spring-boot 2.0, the builder will be autoconfigured for you
    // with the "prototype" scope, meaning each injection point will receive
    // a newly cloned instance of the builder.
    public MyClient(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        webClient = webClientBuilder // you can also just use WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("https://httpbin.org")
                .filter(logRequest()) // here is the magic
                .build();
    }

    // Just example of sending request. This method is NOT part of the answer
    public void send(String path) {
        ClientResponse clientResponse = webClient
                .get().uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(path)
                        .queryParam("param", "value")
                        .build())
                .exchange()
                .block();
        log.info("Response: {}", clientResponse.toEntity(String.class).block());
    }

    // This method returns filter function which will log request data
    private static ExchangeFilterFunction logRequest() {
        return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(clientRequest -> {
            log.info("Request: {} {}", clientRequest.method(), clientRequest.url());
            clientRequest.headers().forEach((name, values) -> values.forEach(value -> log.info("{}={}", name, value)));
            return Mono.just(clientRequest);
        });
    }

}
```

Then just call `myClient.send("get");` and log messages should be there.

Output example:

```
Request: GET https://httpbin.org/get?param=value
header1=value1
header2=value2
```

**Edit**

Some people pointed out in comments that `block()` is bad practice etc. I want to clarify: `block()` call here is just *for demo purposes*. The request logging filter will work anyway. You will not need to add `block()` to your code to make `ExchangeFilterFunction` work. You can use `WebClient` to perform a http-call in a usual way, chaining methods and returning `Mono` up the stack until someone will subscribe to it. The only relevant part of the answer is `logRequest()` filter. You can ignore `send()` method altogether - it is not part of the solution - it just demonstrates that filter works.

Some people also asked how to log the response. To log the response you can write another `ExchangeFilterFunction` and add it to `WebClient`. You can use [`ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFilterFunction.html#ofResponseProcessor-java.util.function.Function-) helper for this purpose just the same way as `ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor` is used. You can use methods of [`ClientResponse`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ClientResponse.html) to get headers/cookies etc.

```
    // This method returns filter function which will log response data
    private static ExchangeFilterFunction logResponse() {
        return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> {
            log.info("Response status: {}", clientResponse.statusCode());
            clientResponse.headers().asHttpHeaders().forEach((name, values) -> values.forEach(value -> log.info("{}={}", name, value)));
            return Mono.just(clientResponse);
        });
    }
```

Don't forget to add it to your `WebClient`:

```
.filter(logResponse())
```

But be careful and do not try to read the response body here in the filter. Because of the stream nature of it, the body can be consumed only once without some kind of buffering wrapper. So, if you will read it in the filter, you will not be able to read it in the subscriber.

If you really need to log the body, you can make the underlying layer (Netty) to do this. See [Matthew Buckett's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55790675/758991) to get the idea.

Comment: IMO, invoking `block()` defeats the purpose of using webclient. We can log request using a filter, but not sure how to log the response from a `Mono<ClientResponse>` without blocking.

Comment: @PavanKumar The `block()` call here is just for demo purpose. The request logging filter will work anyway. To log the response you can write another [`ExchangeFilterFunction`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFilterFunction.html#ofResponseProcessor-java.util.function.Function-) and log the response. But be careful when you log the response body - because of the stream nature of it, it can be consumed only one time without wrapper.

Comment: How to get request body from `clientRequest `?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. As soon as you read the body (to log it), it is inaccessible to the consumer anymore. I think, it can be implemented wrapping the body stream into some buffered stream, but honestly I never done it. And it will eat memory, making reactive programming a little pointless. If you really need to log the body, you can make the underlying layer (Netty) to do this. See [Matthew Buckett's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55790675/758991) to get the idea.

Comment: I don't see this solution practical due to blocking.

Comment: How can we log response along with request?

Comment: not a solution, and i found we have to avoid `block()` for reactive java app..

Comment: Regarding logging the response body - that may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71827275/spring-web-client-how-to-get-response-string-of-failed-request-wrapped-intro-r/71837600#71837600.

Comment: The response without the HTTP Method or URI is not really useful, is there a way to get those along with the response?

Comment: Little note: HttpHeaders, returned by clientRequest.headers(), has a readable tostring method. If it is good for you, it is not necessary to construct the string yourself

Answer (score 70):

In Spring Boot 2.4.0, the HttpClient's wiretap() method has additional parameters you can pass to show full request/response headers and body in ***normal*** human readable format. Use format (AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL).

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
      .wiretap(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), LogLevel.DEBUG, AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL);
ClientHttpConnector conn = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);   

WebClient client =  WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(conn)
            .build();
```

Result:

```
POST /score HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: insomnia/2020.5.2
Content-Type: application/json
access_: 
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0e....
Accept: application/json
content-length: 4506

WRITE: 4506B {"body":{"invocations":[{"id":....


READ: 2048B HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 2271
Server: Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.7.7
Date: Fri, 29 Jan 2021 18:49:53 GMT

{"body":{"results":[.....
```

Comment: We have a new winner! This is simple and works as expected, thank you!

Comment: May I ask what is the value of "com.somepackage" here please? the current package where the HttpClient is? The package where the Webclient instance is? The package of where the http call is being made? (I have all in different classes/ packages)

Comment: @PatPatPat this value will be passed to SLF4J and will be used as a package name when it generates the log line with your trace. So technically any string can go there, but probably better to put this.getClass().getCanonicalName()

Comment: IS this working for WebTestClient logging? I was unsuccessful to implement it.

Comment: Thank's...saved my day and a readable output for request and response.

Comment: This is THE answer to the question.

Comment: If we want to print the body, then this is the correct answer

Comment: for wiretap method I can see only one option wiretap(boolean) in HTTP client. Not able to see 3 argument method. Any idea?

Comment: I had so hoped this would work for me, but didnt in Spring Boot 2.7.0 - codes all in there, builds and runs - just no output ;-(

Comment: This answer produced wiretap logging for me. However all of the values output as <filtered>. For example "Host: <filtered>". How to display values other than <filtered>?

Comment: Just to add to this based on my experience with this method, the `LogLevel` needs to be the same LogLevel that your application logs at. For eg. my config was INFO level logs and it did not work. Once I changed code to `LogLevel.INFO` it started working. 
Also a follow up question to future viewers, can anyone tell me what `ae977468` mean in the below
`2024-01-08 17:15:42,462 [,] [reactor-http-nio-2] INFO  c.p.p.c.g.c.m.s.s.h.WebClientS2SConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2a5ce647.log():148 {} - [ae977468, L:/100.**.*.*:62541 - R:dev.np.site.com/10.***.10.***:443] READ COMPLETE`

Answer (score 62):

You can have netty do logging of the request/responses with by asking it todo wiretaping, if you create your Spring WebClient like this then it enables the wiretap option.

```
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                HttpClient.create().wiretap(true)
            ))
            .build()
```

and then have your logging setup:

```
logging.level.reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient: DEBUG
```

this will log everything for the request/response (including bodies), but the format is not specific to HTTP so not very readable.

Comment: Thank you so much! Although the format isn't very readable it's the only way I found so far to see the actual request and response body going over the wire.

Comment: But you can still use wiretap(HTTP_CLIENT, LogLevel.DEBUG, AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL) instead of wiretap(true)

Answer (score 31):

You don't necessarily need to roll your own logger, `reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler` does it for you. Just configure your logging system for that class to log at DEBUG level:

```
2017-11-23 12:52:04.562 DEBUG 41449 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] r.i.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler   : [id: 0x9183d6da, L:/127.0.0.1:57681 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8000] Writing object DefaultFullHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1, content: UnpooledByteBufAllocator$InstrumentedUnpooledUnsafeHeapByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 0, cap: 0))
GET /api/v1/watch/namespaces/default/events HTTP/1.1
user-agent: ReactorNetty/0.7.1.RELEASE
host: localhost:8000
accept-encoding: gzip
Accept: application/json
content-length: 0
```

One way to have fewer bugs is to not write code whenever possible.

**Nov 2018**:

With `spring-webflux:5.1.2.RELEASE`, the above no longer works. Use the following instead:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions=DEBUG
...
2018-11-06 20:58:58.181 DEBUG 20300 --- [           main] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [2026fbff] HTTP GET http://localhost:8080/stocks/search?symbol=AAPL
2018-11-06 20:58:58.451 DEBUG 20300 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [2026fbff] Response 400 BAD_REQUEST
```

To log headers or form body, set the above to `TRACE` level; however, that's not enough:

```
ExchangeStrategies exchangeStrategies = ExchangeStrategies.withDefaults();
exchangeStrategies
    .messageWriters().stream()
    .filter(LoggingCodecSupport.class::isInstance)
    .forEach(writer -> ((LoggingCodecSupport)writer).setEnableLoggingRequestDetails(true));

client = WebClient.builder()
    .exchangeStrategies(exchangeStrategies)
```

**Mar 2019**:

In response to a question in the comment that asked how to log request and response body, I don’t know if Spring has such a logger but `WebClient` is built on Netty, so enabling debug logging for package `reactor.ipc.netty` should work, along with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15096962/839733) answer.

Comment: I prefer this solution in limited and controlled environments as an easier option for debugging. This is not always recommended as it might expose some sensitive information in headers etc. If a custom filter is plugged, one has an option to parse and hide such sensitive information.

Comment: @PavanKumar Any sort of logging wire transmission may expose sensitive headers like `Authorization`. The OP didn’t ask for hiding them, but *if* that’s a requirement, *then* code may be written. Usually, it’s acceptable to log such headers at DEBUG level.

Comment: Is it possible to log the response as well?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar How should the LoggingHandler be added in the pipeline? The referenced answer isn't sufficient for me as a Netty/Reactor-newbie.

Comment: @AndrasHatvani Please start a new thread, don't hijack this one.

Comment: Could you please provide detailed answer which describes your latest update(Mar 2019) ?

Comment: You should be able to avoid modifying ExchangeStrategies by setting "spring.codec.log-request-details" to true.

Comment: @MichaelBöckling What version of Spring Boot are you referring to? No such property existed when I wrote the answer, and depending on the version, may still not be an option for some users.

Comment: I'm currently on Spring Boot 2.5.2.

Comment: I needed the headers to be logged as well (for dev purposes) and this answer works!

Answer (score 30):

If you don't want to log the body, then this is really easy.

#### Spring Boot >= 2.1.0

Add the following to application.properties:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions=TRACE
spring.http.log-request-details=true
```

The second line causes headers to be included in the log.

#### Spring Boot < 2.1.0

Add the following to application.properties:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions=TRACE
```

Instead of the second line above, you need to declare a class like this:

```
@Configuration
static class LoggingCodecConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(0)
    public CodecCustomizer loggingCodecCustomizer() {
        return (configurer) -> configurer.defaultCodecs()
                .enableLoggingRequestDetails(true);
    }

}
```

Courtesy of [this Brian Clozel answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53447759/159178)

Comment: I like the version for Spring Boot >= 2.1.0 but it only logs `headers={masked}`in my case. Any idea why?

Comment: Ok, sometimes I should search for a solution a bit longer: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-logging-sensitive-data. This explains why it prints masked and how you can disable it.

Comment: @Tobske the second linke from from the >=2.1.0 section takes care of the masked headers, you should not need any further changes. At least that is my experience.

Comment: `spring.http.log-request-details=true`is deprecated in favor of `spring.mvc.log-request-details=true`

Comment: I can not see my request body being logged. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 17):

@Matthew Buckett answer shows you how to get Netty wire logging. However, the format is not very fancy (it includes hex dump). But it can be easily customized via extending `io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`

```
public class HttpLoggingHandler extends LoggingHandler {

    @Override
    protected String format(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String event, Object arg) {
        if (arg instanceof ByteBuf) {
            ByteBuf msg = (ByteBuf) arg;
            return msg.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
        return super.format(ctx, event, arg);
    }
}
```

Then include it in your `WebClient` configuration:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
    .tcpConfiguration(tcpClient ->
        tcpClient.bootstrap(bootstrap ->
            BootstrapHandlers.updateLogSupport(bootstrap, new HttpLoggingHandler())));

WebClient
    .builder()
    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
    .build()
```

Example:

```
webClient.post()
    .uri("https://postman-echo.com/post")
    .syncBody("{\"foo\" : \"bar\"}")
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .exchange()
    .block();
```

```
2019-09-22 18:09:21.477 DEBUG   --- [ctor-http-nio-4] c.e.w.c.e.logging.HttpLoggingHandler     : [id: 0x505be2bb] REGISTERED
2019-09-22 18:09:21.489 DEBUG   --- [ctor-http-nio-4] c.e.w.c.e.logging.HttpLoggingHandler     : [id: 0x505be2bb] CONNECT: postman-echo.com/35.170.134.160:443
2019-09-22 18:09:21.701 DEBUG   --- [ctor-http-nio-4] c.e.w.c.e.logging.HttpLoggingHandler     : [id: 0x505be2bb, L:/192.168.100.35:55356 - R:postman-echo.com/35.170.134.160:443] ACTIVE
2019-09-22 18:09:21.836 DEBUG   --- [ctor-http-nio-4] c.e.w.c.e.logging.HttpLoggingHandler     : [id: 0x505be2bb, L:/192.168.100.35:55356 - R:postman-echo.com/35.170.134.160:443] READ COMPLETE
2019-09-22 18:09:21.905 DEBUG   --- [ctor-http-nio-4] c.e.w.c.e.logging.HttpLoggingHandler     : [id: 0x505be2bb, L:/192.168.100.35:55356 - R:postman-echo.com/35.170.134.160:443] READ COMPLETE
2019-09-22 18:09:22.036 DEBUG   --- [ctor-http-nio-4] c.e.w.c.e.logging.HttpLoggingHandler     : [id: 0x505be2bb, L:/192.168.100.35:55356 - R:postman-echo.com/35.170.134.160:443] USER_EVENT: SslHandshakeCompletionEvent(SUCCESS)
2019-09-22 18:09:22.082 DEBUG   --- [ctor-http-nio-4] c.e.w.c.e.logging.HttpLoggingHandler     : POST /post HTTP/1.1
user-agent: ReactorNetty/0.8.11.RELEASE
host: postman-echo.com
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
content-length: 15

{"foo" : "bar"}
2019-09-22 18:09:22.083 DEBUG   --- [ctor-http-nio-4] c.e.w.c.e.logging.HttpLoggingHandler     : [id: 0x505be2bb, L:/192.168.100.35:55356 - R:postman-echo.com/35.170.134.160:443] FLUSH
2019-09-22 18:09:22.086 DEBUG   --- [ctor-http-nio-4] c.e.w.c.e.logging.HttpLoggingHandler     : [id: 0x505be2bb, L:/192.168.100.35:55356 - R:postman-echo.com/35.170.134.160:443] READ COMPLETE
2019-09-22 18:09:22.217 DEBUG   --- [ctor-http-nio-4] c.e.w.c.e.logging.HttpLoggingHandler     : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 22 Sep 2019 15:09:22 GMT
ETag: W/"151-Llbe8OYGC3GeZCxttuAH3BOYBKA"
Server: nginx
set-cookie: sails.sid=s%3APe39li6V8TL8FOJOzSINZRkQlZ7HFAYi.UkLZjfajJqkq9fUfF2Y8N4JOInHNW5t1XACu3fhQYSc; Path=/; HttpOnly
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 337
Connection: keep-alive

{"args":{},"data":"{\"foo\" : \"bar\"}","files":{},"form":{},"headers":{"x-forwarded-proto":"https","host":"postman-echo.com","content-length":"15","accept":"application/json","content-type":"text/plain;charset=UTF-8","user-agent":"ReactorNetty/0.8.11.RELEASE","x-forwarded-port":"443"},"json":null,"url":"https://postman-echo.com/post"}
2019-09-22 18:09:22.243 DEBUG   --- [ctor-http-nio-4] c.e.w.c.e.logging.HttpLoggingHandler     : [id: 0x505be2bb, L:/192.168.100.35:55356 - R:postman-echo.com/35.170.134.160:443] READ COMPLETE
```

If you want to suppress useless (for you) log entries like (note `ACTIVE` at the end):

```
2019-09-22 18:09:21.701 DEBUG   --- [ctor-http-nio-4] c.e.w.c.e.logging.HttpLoggingHandler     : [id: 0x505be2bb, L:/192.168.100.35:55356 - R:postman-echo.com/35.170.134.160:443] ACTIVE
```

You can override `channelActive` and others like so:

```
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    ctx.fireChannelActive();
}
```

The answer is based on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-log-webclient-calls

Comment: I am on Netty 4.1.38 and this code does not print response content correctly (����$N\;��z�e��>$[�).

Comment: It works after adding the constructor mentioned in the link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-log-webclient-calls

Comment: tcpClient.bootstrap is deprecated and it was not obvious which method to use instead

Comment: Yes, this is a good way to log the body. The drawback is that the response is scattered over multiple log entries.

Comment: For new way to do this refer to [How to customize reactor Netty's HttpClient LoggingHandler without using deprecated methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72540858/2659499)

Answer (score 14):

An update of Feb 2020 for Spring Boot 2.2.4 and Spring 5.2.3:

I did not manage to get `spring.http.log-request-details=true` doing its job, and current [Spring WebFlux reference suggests](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-logging-sensitive-data) that some coding needs be done to have headers logged, though the code example uses deprecated [`exchangeStrategies()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.Builder.html#exchangeStrategies-java.util.function.Consumer-) method.

There is still a replacement for the deprecated method, so a compact piece of code for getting headers logged at WebClient level may look like this:

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
    .codecs(configurer -> configurer.defaultCodecs().enableLoggingRequestDetails(true))
    .build();
```

with further

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions=TRACE
```

It should be noted though that not all of the headers are available (do exist) at WebFlux `ExchangeFunctions` level, so some more logging at Netty `HttpClient` level may be essential too, as per [@Matthew's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55790675/972463):

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
        HttpClient.create()
            .wiretap(true)))
    .build()
```

with further

```
logging.level.reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient: DEBUG
```

This will get bodies logged too.

Answer (score 9):

There is a way to log request and response body using only [ExchangeFilterFunction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFilterFunction.html). It is independent of the underlying `ClientHttpConnector` and supports tailor-made output. The actual output isn't included in the implementation. Instead the lines where request and response body can be accessed contain explanatory comments. Add the following class instance to the `WebClient` filter list:

```
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ClientHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ClientHttpRequestDecorator;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserter;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ClientRequest;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ClientResponse;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFilterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunction;
import reactor.core.publisher.BaseSubscriber;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class LoggingExchangeFilterFunction implements ExchangeFilterFunction {

    @Override
    public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next) {
        BodyInserter<?, ? super ClientHttpRequest> originalBodyInserter = request.body();
        ClientRequest loggingClientRequest = ClientRequest.from(request)
                .body((outputMessage, context) -> {
                    ClientHttpRequestDecorator loggingOutputMessage = new ClientHttpRequestDecorator(outputMessage) {

                        private final AtomicBoolean alreadyLogged = new AtomicBoolean(false); // Not sure if thread-safe is needed...

                        @Override
                        public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
                            boolean needToLog = alreadyLogged.compareAndSet(false, true);
                            if (needToLog) {
                                // use `body.toString(Charset.defaultCharset())` to obtain request body
                            }
                            return super.writeWith(body);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Mono<Void> writeAndFlushWith(Publisher<? extends Publisher<? extends DataBuffer>> body) {
                            boolean needToLog = alreadyLogged.compareAndSet(false, true);
                            if (needToLog) {
                                BaseSubscriber<Publisher<? extends DataBuffer>> bodySubscriber = new BaseSubscriber<Publisher<? extends DataBuffer>>() {
                                    @Override
                                    protected void hookOnNext(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> next) {
                                        // use `next.toString(Charset.defaultCharset())` to obtain request body element
                                    }
                                };
                                body.subscribe(bodySubscriber);
                                bodySubscriber.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
                            }
                            return super.writeAndFlushWith(body);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Mono<Void> setComplete() { // This is for requests with no body (e.g. GET).
                            boolean needToLog = alreadyLogged.compareAndSet(false, true);
                            if (needToLog) {
                                // A request with no body, could log `request.method()` and `request.url()`.
                            }
                            return super.setComplete();
                        }
                    };
                    return originalBodyInserter.insert(loggingOutputMessage, context);
                })
                .build();
        return next.exchange(loggingClientRequest)
                .map(
                        clientResponse -> clientResponse.mutate()
                                .body(f -> f.map(dataBuffer -> {
                                    // Use `dataBuffer.toString(Charset.defaultCharset())` to obtain response body.
                                    return dataBuffer;
                                }))
                                .build()
                );
    }

}
```

Comment: Request is not written. Response is. Need request to subscribe(), too

Answer (score 8):

**Spoiler:** So far the custom logging with the `ExchangeFilterFunction` does not support to log the body.

In my case the best logging is achieved with the solution from Bealdung (see [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-log-webclient-calls#2-logging-with-netty-httpclient)).

Therefore I setup a default builder so the different APIs share this.

```java
@Bean
public WebClient.Builder defaultWebClient() {
    final var builder = WebClient.builder();
    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
        builder.clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                HttpClient.create().wiretap("reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient",
                        LogLevel.DEBUG, AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL)
        ));
    }
    return builder;
}
```

In the concrete API configuration I can then configure specific things:

```java
@Bean
public SpecificApi bspApi(@Value("${specific.api.url}") final String baseUrl,
                     final WebClient.Builder builder) {
    final var webClient = builder.baseUrl(baseUrl).build();
    return new SpecificApi(webClient);
}
```

And then I have to set the following property:

```
logging.level.reactor.netty.http.client: DEBUG
```

Then the request log looks like:

```
021-03-03 12:56:34.589 DEBUG 20464 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [id: 0xe75a7fb8] REGISTERED
2021-03-03 12:56:34.590 DEBUG 20464 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [id: 0xe75a7fb8] CONNECT: /192.168.01:80
2021-03-03 12:56:34.591 DEBUG 20464 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [id: 0xe75a7fb8, L:/192.168.04:56774 - R:/192.168.01:80] ACTIVE
2021-03-03 12:56:34.591 DEBUG 20464 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [id: 0xe75a7fb8, L:/192.168.04:56774 - R:/192.168.01:80] Handler is being applied: {uri=http://192.168.01/user, method=GET}
2021-03-03 12:56:34.592 DEBUG 20464 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [id: 0xe75a7fb8, L:/192.168.04:56774 - R:/192.168.01:80] WRITE: 102B GET /user HTTP/1.1
user-agent: ReactorNetty/1.0.3
host: 192.168.01
accept: */*

<REQUEST_BODY>

2021-03-03 12:56:34.592 DEBUG 20464 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [id: 0xe75a7fb8, L:/192.168.04:56774 - R:/192.168.01:80] FLUSH
2021-03-03 12:56:34.592 DEBUG 20464 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [id: 0xe75a7fb8, L:/192.168.04:56774 - R:/192.168.01:80] WRITE: 0B 
2021-03-03 12:56:34.592 DEBUG 20464 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [id: 0xe75a7fb8, L:/192.168.04:56774 - R:/192.168.01:80] FLUSH
2021-03-03 12:56:34.594 DEBUG 20464 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [id: 0xe75a7fb8, L:/192.168.04:56774 - R:/192.168.01:80] READ: 2048B HTTP/1.1 200 
Server: nginx/1.16.1
Date: Wed, 03 Mar 2021 11:56:31 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 4883
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Range: items 0-4/4

<RESPONSE_BODY>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me with quite useful log details

Comment: this worked for me instead of this.javaClass.canonicalName. i got macos exception when i use the canonicalName

Answer (score 8):

Getting request/response logging right is somehow really difficult when it comes to Spring's reactive WebClient.

I had the following requirements:

- Log request and response **including bodies** in *one* log statement (it's so much more convenient to have it all in one statement if you scroll through hundreds of logs in AWS cloudwatch)
- Filter sensitive data such as personal data or financial data from the logs to be compliant with GDPR and PCI

[Wiretapping Netty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66456679/287138) or using [custom Jackson en-/decoders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62858230/287138) was therefore not an option.

Here's my take on the problem (again based on Stanislav's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67939497/287138)).

(The following code uses [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org) annotation processing, which you probably want to use as well, if you don't use it yet. Otherwise it should be easy to de-lombok)

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ClientHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ClientHttpRequestDecorator;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.util.StopWatch;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserter;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ClientRequest;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ClientResponse;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFilterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunction;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import static java.lang.Math.min;
import static java.util.UUID.randomUUID;
import static net.logstash.logback.argument.StructuredArguments.v;

@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RequestLoggingFilterFunction implements ExchangeFilterFunction {

  private static final int MAX_BYTES_LOGGED = 4_096;

  private final String externalSystem;

  @Override
  @NonNull
  public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(@NonNull ClientRequest request, @NonNull ExchangeFunction next) {
    if (!log.isDebugEnabled()) {
      return next.exchange(request);
    }

    var clientRequestId = randomUUID().toString();

    var requestLogged = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    var responseLogged = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    var capturedRequestBody = new StringBuilder();
    var capturedResponseBody = new StringBuilder();

    var stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    stopWatch.start();

    return next
      .exchange(ClientRequest.from(request).body(new BodyInserter<>() {

        @Override
        @NonNull
        public Mono<Void> insert(@NonNull ClientHttpRequest req, @NonNull Context context) {
          return request.body().insert(new ClientHttpRequestDecorator(req) {

            @Override
            @NonNull
            public Mono<Void> writeWith(@NonNull Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
              return super.writeWith(Flux.from(body).doOnNext(data -> capturedRequestBody.append(extractBytes(data)))); // number of bytes appended is maxed in real code
            }

          }, context);
        }
      }).build())
      .doOnNext(response -> {
          if (!requestLogged.getAndSet(true)) {
            log.debug("| >>---> Outgoing {} request [{}]\n{} {}\n{}\n\n{}\n",
              v("externalSystem", externalSystem),
              v("clientRequestId", clientRequestId),
              v("clientRequestMethod", request.method()),
              v("clientRequestUrl", request.url()),
              v("clientRequestHeaders", request.headers()), // filtered in real code
              v("clientRequestBody", capturedRequestBody.toString()) // filtered in real code
            );
          }
        }
      )
      .doOnError(error -> {
        if (!requestLogged.getAndSet(true)) {
          log.debug("| >>---> Outgoing {} request [{}]\n{} {}\n{}\n\nError: {}\n",
            v("externalSystem", externalSystem),
            v("clientRequestId", clientRequestId),
            v("clientRequestMethod", request.method()),
            v("clientRequestUrl", request.url()),
            v("clientRequestHeaders", request.headers()), // filtered in real code
            error.getMessage()
          );
        }
      })
      .map(response -> response.mutate().body(transformer -> transformer
          .doOnNext(body -> capturedResponseBody.append(extractBytes(body))) // number of bytes appended is maxed in real code
          .doOnTerminate(() -> {
            if (stopWatch.isRunning()) {
              stopWatch.stop();
            }
          })
          .doOnComplete(() -> {
            if (!responseLogged.getAndSet(true)) {
              log.debug("| <---<< Response for outgoing {} request [{}] after {}ms\n{} {}\n{}\n\n{}\n",
                v("externalSystem", externalSystem),
                v("clientRequestId", clientRequestId),
                v("clientRequestExecutionTimeInMillis", stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis()),
                v("clientResponseStatusCode", response.statusCode().value()),
                v("clientResponseStatusPhrase", response.statusCode().getReasonPhrase()),
                v("clientResponseHeaders", response.headers().asHttpHeaders(), // HttpHeaders implement toString() with formatting, filtered in real code
                v("clientResponseBody", capturedResponseBody.toString()) // filtered in real code
              );
            }
          })
          .doOnError(error -> {
              if (!responseLogged.getAndSet(true)) {
                log.debug("| <---<< Error parsing response for outgoing {} request [{}] after {}ms\n{}",
                  v("externalSystem", externalSystem),
                  v("clientRequestId", clientRequestId),
                  v("clientRequestExecutionTimeInMillis", stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis()),
                  v("clientErrorMessage", error.getMessage())
                );
              }
            }
          )
        ).build()
      );
  }

  private static String extractBytes(DataBuffer data) {
    int currentReadPosition = data.readPosition();
    var numberOfBytesLogged = min(data.readableByteCount(), MAX_BYTES_LOGGED);
    var bytes = new byte[numberOfBytesLogged];
    data.read(bytes, 0, numberOfBytesLogged);
    data.readPosition(currentReadPosition);
    return new String(bytes);
  }

}
```

Log entries look like this for successful exchanges:

```
2021-12-07 17:14:04.029 DEBUG --- [ctor-http-nio-3] RequestLoggingFilterFunction        : | >>---> Outgoing SnakeOil request [6abd0170-d682-4ca6-806c-bbb3559998e8]
POST https://localhost:8101/snake-oil/oauth/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=*****&client_secret=*****
```

```
2021-12-07 17:14:04.037 DEBUG --- [ctor-http-nio-3] RequestLoggingFilterFunction        : | <---<< Response for outgoing SnakeOil request [6abd0170-d682-4ca6-806c-bbb3559998e8] after 126ms
200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: [Accept-Encoding, User-Agent]
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{"access_token":"*****","expires_in":"3600","token_type":"BearerToken"}
```

Error conditions are handled gracefully as well, of course.

Comment: any sample on how you did the masking of token?

Answer (score 7):

This is what worked for me in 2021 :)

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient
        .create()
        .wiretap(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(),
                LogLevel.INFO, AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL);

WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl("https://example.com")
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
        .build();
```

Comment: What about WebTestClient? not WebClient. It did not work for WebTestClient.

Comment: Use ```LogLevel.DEBUG``` and include this in your ```application.yml```: ```logging.level.reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient: DEBUG```

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Stanislav Burov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67939497/4110190)'s answer I made this logger, that logs all request/response headers, method, url and body.

```
public class WebClientLogger implements ExchangeFilterFunction {

@Override
public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next) {
    // Log url using 'request.url()'
    // Log method using 'request.method()'
    // Log request headers using 'request.headers().entrySet().stream().map(Object::toString).collect(joining(","))'

    BodyInserter<?, ? super ClientHttpRequest> originalBodyInserter = request.body();

    ClientRequest loggingClientRequest = ClientRequest.from(request)
            .body((outputMessage, context) -> {
                ClientHttpRequestDecorator loggingOutputMessage = new ClientHttpRequestDecorator(outputMessage) {
                    private final AtomicBoolean alreadyLogged = new AtomicBoolean(false);

                    @Override
                    public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
                        boolean needToLog = alreadyLogged.compareAndSet(false, true);
                        if (needToLog) {

                            body = DataBufferUtils.join(body)
                                    .doOnNext(content -> {
                                        // Log request body using 'content.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)'
                                    });
                        }
                        return super.writeWith(body);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Mono<Void> setComplete() { // This is for requests with no body (e.g. GET).
                        boolean needToLog = alreadyLogged.compareAndSet(false, true);
                        if (needToLog) {
                            
                        }
                        return super.setComplete();
                    }
                };

                return originalBodyInserter.insert(loggingOutputMessage, context);
            })
            .build();

    return next.exchange(loggingClientRequest)
            .map(clientResponse -> {
                        // Log response status using 'clientResponse.statusCode().value())'
                        // Log response headers using 'clientResponse.headers().asHttpHeaders().entrySet().stream().map(Object::toString).collect(joining(","))'

                        return clientResponse.mutate()
                                .body(f -> f.map(dataBuffer -> {
                                    // Log response body using 'dataBuffer.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)'
                                    return dataBuffer;
                                }))
                                .build();
                    }
            );

}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Here's my snippet based on excellent Stanislav Burov's answer. I extracted some lambdas to standalone classes to make code more readable for me and I also implemented a limited UTF-8 aware decoder. I'm using some Guava and Java 17 features, but this code could be easily ported to early versions. I don't buffer the whole request/response body, but rather log buffers as they come in a separate calls, so it does not use excessive RAM or writes extremely long lines.

```java
package kz.doubleservices.healthbus.util;

import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ClientHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ClientHttpRequestDecorator;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserter;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ClientRequest;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ClientResponse;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFilterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunction;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.HexFormat;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.function.Function;

import static com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding.base32;

public class LoggingExchangeFilterFunction implements ExchangeFilterFunction {
    private final Logger logger;

    public LoggingExchangeFilterFunction(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(@NonNull ClientRequest request, @NonNull ExchangeFunction next) {
        if (!logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            return next.exchange(request);
        }

        String requestId = generateRequestId();

        if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
            var message = new StringBuilder();
            message.append("HTTP request start; request-id=").append(requestId).append('\n')
                    .append(request.method()).append(' ').append(request.url());
            request.headers().forEach((String name, List<String> values) -> {
                for (String value : values) {
                    message.append('\n').append(name).append(": ").append(value);
                }
            });
            logger.trace(message.toString());
        } else {
            logger.debug("HTTP request; request-id=" + requestId + '\n' +
                         request.method() + ' ' + request.url());
        }

        if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
            var bodyInserter = new LoggingBodyInserter(logger, requestId, request.body());
            request = ClientRequest.from(request).body(bodyInserter).build();
        }

        return next.exchange(request).map(new LoggingClientResponseTransformer(logger, requestId));
    }

    private static String generateRequestId() {
        var bytes = new byte[5];
        ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBytes(bytes);
        return base32().encode(bytes).toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
    }

    private static class LoggingBodyInserter implements BodyInserter<Object, ClientHttpRequest> {
        private final Logger logger;
        private final String requestId;
        private final BodyInserter<?, ? super ClientHttpRequest> originalBodyInserter;

        private LoggingBodyInserter(Logger logger, String requestId,
                                    BodyInserter<?, ? super ClientHttpRequest> originalBodyInserter) {
            this.logger = logger;
            this.requestId = requestId;
            this.originalBodyInserter = originalBodyInserter;
        }

        @Override
        @NonNull
        public Mono<Void> insert(@NonNull ClientHttpRequest outputMessage, @NonNull Context context) {
            var loggingOutputMessage = new LoggingClientHttpRequestDecorator(outputMessage, logger, requestId);
            return originalBodyInserter.insert(loggingOutputMessage, context);
        }
    }

    private static class LoggingClientHttpRequestDecorator extends ClientHttpRequestDecorator {
        private final Logger logger;
        private final String requestId;

        public LoggingClientHttpRequestDecorator(ClientHttpRequest delegate, Logger logger, String requestId) {
            super(delegate);
            this.logger = logger;
            this.requestId = requestId;
        }

        @Override
        @NonNull
        public Mono<Void> writeWith(@NonNull Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
            Flux<? extends DataBuffer> loggingBody = Flux.from(body)
                    .doOnNext(this::logDataBuffer)
                    .doOnComplete(this::logComplete)
                    .doOnError(this::logError);
            return super.writeWith(loggingBody);
        }

        @Override
        @NonNull
        public Mono<Void> setComplete() {
            logger.trace("HTTP request end; request-id=" + requestId);
            return super.setComplete();
        }

        private void logDataBuffer(DataBuffer dataBuffer) {
            int readPosition = dataBuffer.readPosition();
            byte[] data = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
            dataBuffer.read(data);
            dataBuffer.readPosition(readPosition);
            logger.trace("HTTP request data; request-id=" + requestId + '\n' + bytesToString(data));
        }

        private void logComplete() {
            logger.trace("HTTP request end; request-id=" + requestId);
        }

        private void logError(Throwable exception) {
            logger.trace("HTTP request error; request-id=" + requestId, exception);
        }
    }

    private static class LoggingClientResponseTransformer implements Function<ClientResponse, ClientResponse> {
        private final Logger logger;
        private final String requestId;

        private LoggingClientResponseTransformer(Logger logger, String requestId) {
            this.logger = logger;
            this.requestId = requestId;
        }

        @Override
        public ClientResponse apply(ClientResponse clientResponse) {
            if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                var message = new StringBuilder();
                message.append("HTTP response start; request-id=").append(requestId).append('\n')
                        .append("HTTP ").append(clientResponse.statusCode());
                clientResponse.headers().asHttpHeaders().forEach((String name, List<String> values) -> {
                    for (String value : values) {
                        message.append('\n').append(name).append(": ").append(value);
                    }
                });
                logger.trace(message.toString());
            } else {
                logger.debug("HTTP response; request-id=" + requestId + '\n' +
                             "HTTP " + clientResponse.statusCode());
            }

            return clientResponse.mutate()
                    .body(new ClientResponseBodyTransformer(logger, requestId))
                    .build();
        }
    }

    private static class ClientResponseBodyTransformer implements Function<Flux<DataBuffer>, Flux<DataBuffer>> {
        private final Logger logger;
        private final String requestId;
        private boolean completed = false;

        private ClientResponseBodyTransformer(Logger logger, String requestId) {
            this.logger = logger;
            this.requestId = requestId;
        }

        @Override
        public Flux<DataBuffer> apply(Flux<DataBuffer> body) {
            return body
                    .doOnNext(this::logDataBuffer)
                    .doOnComplete(this::logComplete)
                    .doOnError(this::logError);
        }

        private void logDataBuffer(DataBuffer dataBuffer) {
            int readPosition = dataBuffer.readPosition();
            byte[] data = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
            dataBuffer.read(data);
            dataBuffer.readPosition(readPosition);
            logger.trace("HTTP response data; request-id=" + requestId + '\n' + bytesToString(data));
        }

        private void logComplete() {
            if (!completed) {
                logger.trace("HTTP response end; request-id=" + requestId);
                completed = true;
            }
        }

        private void logError(Throwable exception) {
            logger.trace("HTTP response error; request-id=" + requestId, exception);
        }
    }

    private static String bytesToString(byte[] bytes) {
        var string = new StringBuilder(bytes.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            byte b1 = bytes[i];
            if (b1 >= 0) {
                if (32 <= b1 && b1 < 127) { // ordinary ASCII characters
                    string.append((char) b1);
                } else {  // control characters
                    switch (b1) {
                        case '\t' -> string.append("\\t");
                        case '\n' -> string.append("\\n");
                        case '\r' -> string.append("\\r");
                        default -> {
                            string.append("\\x");
                            HexFormat.of().toHexDigits(string, b1);
                        }
                    }
                }
                continue;
            }
            if ((b1 & 0xe0) == 0xc0) { // UTF-8 first byte of 2-bytes sequence
                i++;
                if (i < bytes.length) {
                    byte b2 = bytes[i];
                    if ((b2 & 0xc0) == 0x80) { // UTF-8 second byte of 2-bytes sequence
                        char c = (char) ((b1 & 0x1f) << 6 | b2 & 0x3f);
                        if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
                            string.append(c);
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    string.append("\\x");
                    HexFormat.of().toHexDigits(string, b1);
                    string.append("\\x");
                    HexFormat.of().toHexDigits(string, b2);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            string.append("\\x");
            HexFormat.of().toHexDigits(string, b1);
        }
        return string.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those asking about the same with `WebTestClient` the answer is very similar:

```
final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient
  .create()
  .wiretap(
    this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), 
    LogLevel.INFO, 
    AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL);

final WebTestClient webTestClient = WebTestClient
  .bindToServer(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
  .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to efficiently log the request and response fully with their body as one message without calling `block()` method.

At first glance, the task seemed simple, since the `ExchangeFilterFunction` is similar to the `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` (which was used for `RestTemplate`).

The problems I found:

1. It's almost impossible to retrieve request body. Everything you have is `BodyInserter` which don't want share the data. Solution is to make clone of client request that accesses the body using override.

   ```
    private static ClientRequest writeBody(ClientRequest request, StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
    return ClientRequest.from(request)
            .body((outputMessage, context) -> request.body().insert(new ClientHttpRequestDecorator(outputMessage) {
                @Override
                public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
                    return super.writeWith(Mono.from(body)
                            .doOnNext(dataBuffer -> stringBuilder.append(dataBuffer.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
                }
            }, context))
            .build();
         }
   ```
2. Data can't be read twice. It's easy to retrieve response body using `bodyToMono` or `body` methods of ClientResponse. But if data become read in filter then output will be null. Solution to create a copy of the response, body become unread:

   ```
    var builder = ClientResponse.from(c);
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(responseBodyBuilder)) {
        builder.body(responseBodyBuilder.toString());
    }
    return builder.build();
   ```

Full filter method.

```
   @Override
public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next) {
    StringBuilder requestBodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder responseBodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    return next.exchange(writeBody(request, requestBodyBuilder))
            .flatMap(clientResponse -> {
                return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class)
                        .map(body -> {
                            responseBodyBuilder.append(body);
                            return clientResponse;
                        });
            })
            .map(c -> {
                var builder = ClientResponse.from(c);
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(responseBodyBuilder)) {
                    builder.body(responseBodyBuilder.toString());
                }
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                stringBuilder.append(logRequest(request, requestBodyBuilder.toString()));
                stringBuilder.append(logResponse(c, responseBodyBuilder.toString()));
                log.info(stringBuilder.toString());
                return builder.build();
            });
}


   private static String logResponse(ClientResponse clientResponse, String body) {
    String result;
    // usage of clientResponse (statusCode/headers/etc) and body
    return result;
}

    private static String logRequest(ClientRequest clientRequest, String body) {
    String result;
    // usage of clientRequest (url/method/headers/etc) and body
    return result;
}
```

This way, you can record the request body and the response body and, if necessary, do it in one message.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to log the serialized version of the JSON in the request or response, you can create your own Json Encoder/Decoder classes that wrap the defaults and log the JSON. Specifically you would subclass the `Jackson2JsonEncoder` and `Jackson2JsonDecoder` classes and override the methods that expose the serial data.

This is explained here: https://andrew-flower.com/blog/webclient-body-logging

The approach shown above is focused mainly on non-streaming data.  Doing it for streaming data might be more challenging.

It's obviously not recommended to do this in a Prod environment due to extra memory / processing required, but configuring it for development environments is useful.

Answer (score 0):

[@StasKolodyuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3503685/staskolodyuk)'s answer elaborates on the solution from [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-log-webclient-calls) for logging the response body of a reactive WebClient. Note that

```
tc.bootstrap(...)
```

is deprecated in

```
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient
      .create()
      .tcpConfiguration(
        tc -> tc.bootstrap(
          b -> BootstrapHandlers.updateLogSupport(b, new CustomLogger(HttpClient.class))))
      .build()
```

Another non-deprecated way to add your custom LoggingHandler is (Kotlin)

```
val httpClient: HttpClient = HttpClient.create().mapConnect { conn, b ->
    BootstrapHandlers.updateLogSupport(b, CustomLogger(HttpClient::class.java))
    conn
}
```

Comment: `BootstrapHandlers.updateLogSupport` is also deprecated. For the new way refer to [How to customize reactor Netty's HttpClient LoggingHandler without using deprecated methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72540858/2659499)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to implement CustomLoggerHandler, don't forget to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`, otherwise will be a memory leak https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/988#issuecomment-582489035

Answer (score 0):

You can do trace webclient logs including request and response body payload with some manipulations using filter function:

```
public class TracingExchangeFilterFunction implements ExchangeFilterFunction {


    return next.exchange(buildTraceableRequest(request))
            .flatMap(response ->
                    response.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers())
                            .next()
                            .doOnNext(dataBuffer -> traceResponse(response, dataBuffer))
                            .thenReturn(response)) ;
}

private ClientRequest buildTraceableRequest( 
        final ClientRequest clientRequest) {
    return ClientRequest.from(clientRequest).body(
            new BodyInserter<>() {
                @Override
                public Mono<Void> insert(
                        final ClientHttpRequest outputMessage,
                        final Context context) {
                    return clientRequest.body().insert(
                            new ClientHttpRequestDecorator(outputMessage) {
                                @Override
                                public Mono<Void> writeWith(final Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
                                    return super.writeWith(
                                            from(body).doOnNext(buffer ->
                                                    traceRequest(clientRequest, buffer)));
                                }
                            }, context);
                }
            }).build();
}

private void traceRequest(ClientRequest clientRequest, DataBuffer buffer) {
    final ByteBuf byteBuf = NettyDataBufferFactory.toByteBuf(buffer);
    final byte[] bytes = ByteBufUtil.getBytes(byteBuf);
    // do some tracing
}


private void traceResponse(ClientResponse response, DataBuffer dataBuffer) {
    final byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
    dataBuffer.read(bytes);
    // do some tracing
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to capture it outside the application with a tool.

E.g. [netcat](https://nmap.org/ncat/). Run netcat in listen mode and post request to it. It'll show the full request (headers + body).

```
$ printf 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\nbye\n' | nc -lk 9090 || break    

..
client.baseUrl("http://localhost:9090")
..
```

This is a portable solution and should work across clients/tech-stack.