# Spring WebClient - logging is2xxSuccessful HTTPStatus

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am downloading files using Spring WebClient like below:

```
private void dnloadFileAPI(String theId, String destination) {
        log.info("Downloading file.. " + theId);
        Flux<DataBuffer> dataBuffer = webClient
                .get()
                .uri("/some/fancy/" + theId + "/api")
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is2xxSuccessful, response -> Mono.just(new CustomException("Success")))
                .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);
        DataBufferUtils.write(dataBuffer, Paths.get(destination), StandardOpenOption.CREATE).share().block();
    }
```

File(s) get downloaded fine. The only piece I am struggling is, when the response is 200, I just want to log one line like this:

```
log.info("{}", theId + " - File downloaded successfully")
```

I tried this too but didnt get what I am looking for - [How to log Spring WebClient response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50216067/how-to-log-spring-webclient-response)

In short, is there some way above can be achieved without writing a separate `CustomException` ? Feeling lost and clueless here. Any pointers in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding the following after the `bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class)` line will be what you need

```
.doOnComplete(() -> log.info("File downloaded successfully"))
```

Something like this

```
private void dnloadFileAPI(String theId, String destination) {
    log.info("Downloading file.. " + theId);
    Flux<DataBuffer> dataBuffer = webClient
        .get()
        .uri("/some/fancy/" + theId + "/api")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class)
        .doOnComplete(() -> log.info("File downloaded successfully"));
    DataBufferUtils.write(dataBuffer, Paths.get(destination), StandardOpenOption.CREATE).share().block();
}
```

Comment: Dang...!! so much to learn !!! `.doOnComplete(..)` was exactly I was looking for. ! I don't need `.onStatus(...)` now. Thanks a million @athom.

Answer (score 0):

We can used doOnSuccess method

```
.doOnSuccess(response -> logger.info("File downloaded successfully"))
```

Spring-webflux version 5.3.22