# Set WebClient.Builder.exchangeStrategies() without losing Spring Jackson configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, spring-webflux

I'm using the following code (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47463190/159178)) to configure headers to be logged on WebClient requests:

```
ExchangeStrategies exchangeStrategies = ExchangeStrategies.withDefaults();
exchangeStrategies
    .messageWriters().stream()
    .filter(LoggingCodecSupport.class::isInstance)
    .forEach(writer -> ((LoggingCodecSupport)writer).setEnableLoggingRequestDetails(true));

client = WebClient.builder()
    .exchangeStrategies(exchangeStrategies)
```

This works, but causes my Jackson configuration to be lost. In my application.properties I have:

```
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non-null
spring.jackson.deserialization.accept-empty-string-as-null-object=true
```

which gets overwritten by the above code. Here is my workaround:

```
  @Autowired ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @Bean
  WebClientCustomizer webClientCustomizer() {
    return (WebClient.Builder builder) -> {
      builder
          .exchangeStrategies(createExchangeStrategiesWhichLogHeaders())
    };
  }

  private ExchangeStrategies createExchangeStrategiesWhichLogHeaders() {
    ExchangeStrategies exchangeStrategies =
        ExchangeStrategies.builder()
            .codecs(
                clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer -> {
                  clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer
                      .defaultCodecs()
                      .jackson2JsonEncoder(
                          new Jackson2JsonEncoder(objectMapper, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
                  clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer
                      .defaultCodecs()
                      .jackson2JsonDecoder(
                          new Jackson2JsonDecoder(objectMapper, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
                })
            .build();

    exchangeStrategies
        .messageWriters()
        .stream()
        .filter(LoggingCodecSupport.class::isInstance)
        .forEach(writer -> ((LoggingCodecSupport) writer).setEnableLoggingRequestDetails(true));

    return exchangeStrategies;
  }
```

This works, but feels a bit strange. The question is: do I need to include the jackson/objectMapper configuration like this, or is there a simpler way to avoid the Spring objectMapper configuration being overwritten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Spring Boot 2.1.0, you can achieve this by enabling the following property:

```
spring.http.log-request-details=true
```

If you're on a previous Spring Boot version, you should be able to customize this without overwriting or rebuilding the whole configuration, like this:

```
@Configuration
static class LoggingCodecConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(0)
    public CodecCustomizer loggingCodecCustomizer() {
        return (configurer) -> configurer.defaultCodecs()
                .enableLoggingRequestDetails(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: In Spring Boot 2.7.x, this property is deprecated in favour of `spring.codec.log-request-details`. But I do not recommend it, it does not log the request and response bodies, and the header values are logged as `<filtered>`.