# how to get the raw http request/response url/header/body information from spring webclient

Tags: spring, logging, webclient

Its an old question asked by someone, e.g. [how to log Spring 5 WebClient call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154994/how-to-log-spring-5-webclient-call), [Spring Boot - How to log all requests and responses with exceptions in single place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744875/spring-boot-how-to-log-all-requests-and-responses-with-exceptions-in-single-pl)

Above solutions have limitation, e.g. webclient solution can't log body info and not sure the log level can be dynamically changed without restart.

So, as a spring webclient consumer, because webclient wrap low level things for us, e.g. http client, servlet, http stuff, etc. So I think its natural for webclient to give us some additional info as titled, because these info is more often needed, especially when debugging, trouble shooting. you know sometime we print the entity bean may be not exactly the http messages send out or received. and also sometime we need to know the header info. all these info can be logged based on dynamically configurable log level. So its better webclient can supply an interface to get these info from somewhere and let consumer to use it convenient.

Thanks.