# How to intercept http response traffic in Spring WebClient / DataBuffer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webclient

How can I intercept `WebClient` XML responses before they are converted from bytes to DTO?

I tried adding an `exchangeStrategy`, but how could I convert `DataBuffer` to String, and afterwards still invoke the `super.decode()` method?

```
ExchangeStrategies.builder().codecs((configurer) -> {
    configurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(new Jaxb2XmlDecoder() {
        @Override
        public Flux<Object> decode(Publisher<DataBuffer> inputStream, ResolvableType elementType, MimeType mimeType, Map<String, Object> hints) {
            //TODO how to log the response as string content? 
            return super.decode(inputStream, elementType, mimeType, hints);
        }
    }));
```

I succeeded as follows, but I don't know if that is the correct solution? Especially returning an empty collection inside the `flatMapInterable()` feels wrong, but I did not find another way to make it work.

```
@Override
public Flux<Object> decode(Publisher<DataBuffer> inputStream, ResolvableType elementType, MimeType mimeType, Map<String, Object> hints) {
    return DataBufferUtils.join(inputStream)
            .flatMapIterable(buffer -> {
                try {
                    LOGGER.info(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(buffer.asByteBuffer()).toString());
                    return Collections.emptyList();
                } finally {
                    DataBufferUtils.release(buffer);
                }
            })
            .map(arg -> super.decode(inputStream, elementType, mimeType, hints));
}
```

Problem: `map()` is not executed anymore due to the fact that I already read the `DataBuffer`. How could I read it multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

So far I came up with the following solution. It works, but I'm still open for improvements as I don't even know if I'm doing this correctly here.

```
@Override
public Flux<Object> decode(Publisher<DataBuffer> inputStream, ResolvableType elementType, MimeType mimeType, Map<String, Object> hints) {
    return DataBufferUtils.join(inputStream)
            .doOnNext(buf -> LOGGER.info(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(buf.asByteBuffer()).toString()))
            .flatMapMany(buf -> super.decode(Mono.fromSupplier(() -> buf), elementType, mimeType, hints));
}
```