# How to determine if Spring WebClient is using HTTP/2?

Tags: spring-webflux, http2, spring-webclient, spring5

I would like to know whether Spring WebClient is using HTTP/2. How I can determine that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Server Support for HTTP/2**

> As of Spring Framework 5.1 (Reactor Netty 0.8), this server supports as well HTTP/2. JDK9+ deployments will support that protocol without specific infrastructure changes.

Reactor is the underlying http client that is used by Spring WebClient. As of Spring Framework 5.1 this support HTTP/2.

See also [Spring Framework: HTTP/2 support](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/HTTP-2-support) for an overview.

**HTTP/2 is negotiated per connection**

Wether your request *connection* is using HTTP/2 or HTTP/1.1 is **negotiated** per connection between client and server using [ALPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-Layer_Protocol_Negotiation). The server *present* what http versions it is supporting, then the client is choosing HTTP/2 if both parts support it. This is done over TLS in the handshake, so it can not be detected without terminating the TLS connection.

Answer (score 7):

Spring WebClient uses `ReactorClientHttpConnector` (A Reactor-Netty implementation of `ClientHttpConnector`) by default. And according to this [wiki](https://github.com/http2/http2-spec/wiki/Implementations) Netty http-client does support HTTP/2 already.

If you want to check if your Spring WebClient is using HTTP/2 you can use tools like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to intercept your requests and analyse which protocol it is using.

Comment: as @Jonas mentioned - HTTP2 is behind TLS so it is not possible to check without terminating TLS connection, so Wireshark only is not enough

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this answer on stackoverflow:

reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler does it for you. Just configure your logging system for that class to log at DEBUG level.

Where the output is something like:

2017-11-23 12:52:04.562 DEBUG 41449 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] r.i.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler   : [id: 0x9183d6da, L:/127.0.0.1:57681 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8000] Writing object DefaultFullHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1, content: UnpooledByteBufAllocator$InstrumentedUnpooledUnsafeHeapByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 0, cap: 0))
GET /api/v1/watch/namespaces/default/events HTTP/1.1

Perhaps I am wrong, but isn't HTTP/1.1 the output you would want?
If so, check this thread:

[how to log Spring 5 WebClient call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154994/how-to-log-spring-5-webclient-call)

Comment: afaik you are not able to see whether HTTP2 was used from http level - it's present on TCP/TLS level