# Disable Spring Boot Webclient logs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I want to build a simple Spring Web Client who send message from stdin but the WebClient show all [debug informations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7q8K.png) on stdout.

How to disable the logs generated by Webclient ?

Code of the client

```
WebClient webclient = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/").build();
webClient.post().uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/test").queryParam("id",1).build()).retrieve().bodyToMono(Log.class).block();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can customize your logs as you want. as the image you mention,
Go to the application.properties put logger values to disable as `OFF` [io.netty]

```
logging.level.io.netty=off
```

do you want to fully disable all logs from your project, disable `root` below.

```
logging.level.root=off
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. Maybe it's because I'm directly using a webclient in a main without using springbootaplication? I will edit my post to show the client code.

Comment: Please try out with this ```logging.level.reactor.netty.http.client=OFF```

Comment: and refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154994/how-to-log-spring-5-webclient-call

Comment: Ok, it work but only if i use @SpringBootApplication and SpringApplication.run(testClient.class, args); 

Do you think there is an alternative without that?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not familiar much with spring web client bro. anyway please refer this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154994/how-to-log-spring-5-webclient-call

Answer (score 2):

WebClient uses the standard HTTPClient to work, and when initialized, it connects the SLF4J facade for logging. Facade iterates over several frameworks known to it, looking for the one set in the Classpath.

Spring WebClent installs Logback as a dependency.

SLF4J starts working through Logback, and can be configured using the logback.xml configuration file

```
<configuration>
    <root level="OFF">
    </root>
</configuration>
```