# Change Spring Webclient log level from DEBUG to WARN or ERROR

Tags: java, logging, spring-webclient

I have a very simple java application (not spring boot application), in which I am using Spring WebClient to parallely make HTTP calls. I have initialised it in global as below :

```
private static final WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();
```

and using it across my application. Now the issue is that when it starts, it prints a message as following :

```
21:10:59.417 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
```

After that it starts to print all(a ton of) debug logs, which hamper my capability to test and application

Is there any way to change the log level if WebClient is used as above, and not in SpringApplication ? I have tried all solutions offered in [Disable Spring Boot Webclient logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65481011/disable-spring-boot-webclient-logs), and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the level in application.properties like

```
logging.level.root= INFO
```

Comment: No above is not working, it is almost same as the other answer which I wrote in the question. Also as I wrote I don't have a Spring Boot application, it is a normal java application which runs from the main class, very basic. It doesn't scan any application properties as a Spring Application does and maps it to the necessary values.