# Spring Web Client - How to get response string of failed request wrapped intro retrials

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient, spring-retry

#### A little background

I would like to call service's APIs, while doing retries on `5xx` errors. Also, I would like to get an access to every failed request (for logging purposes).

#### Code

```java
getClient()
     .get()
     .uri("http://example.com")
     .retrieve()
     .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, rsp -> Mono.error(new ApiServerException("Server error", rsp.rawStatusCode())))
     .bodyToMono(ReportListResponse.class)
     .retryWhen(
          Retry
               .backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
               .filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof ApiServerException)
     )
     .block();
```

#### Issue

How can I achieve the goal of being able to access the response of every failed request? I was trying to retrieve the body while using `rsp.bodyToMono(String.class)` in `onStatus` method. Unfortunately it didn't give me an expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use `response.bodyToMono` in the `onStatus` to get response body. The following example shows how to deserialize body into `String` but you could define POJO as well.

```
getClient()
        .get()
        .uri("http://example.com")
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, response ->
                response.bodyToMono(String.class)
                        .doOnNext(responseBody ->
                                log.error("Error response from server: {}", responseBody)
                        )
                        // throw original error
                        .then(response.createException())
        )
        .bodyToMono(ReportListResponse.class)
    }
```