# How to customize reactor Netty's HttpClient LoggingHandler without using deprecated methods?

Tags: reactor-netty

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58050657/2659499) is dependent on deprecated method `HttpClient.create().tcpConfiguration` and `BootstrapHandlers` class.

Basically I want to create

```java
public class HttpLoggingHandler extends LoggingHandler
```

and configure `HttpClient`

How the same can be achieved using reactor-netty version `1.0.13` and above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the lifecycle callbacks provided by Reactor Netty (more information [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_lifecycle_callbacks_4))

```
HttpClient.create()
          .doOnChannelInit((observer, channel, remoteAddress) ->
                  channel.pipeline()
                         .addFirst(new LoggingHandler("reactor.netty.examples")));
```