# Spring boot HttpClient logging

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactor-netty

Can you help me re-write the below snippet as the bootstrap and HttpClient.from(tcp) are deprecated:

TcpClient.bootstrap(bootstrap -> BootstrapHandlers.updateLogSupport(bootstrap, new HttpLoggingHandler()))

webClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.from(tcpClient)))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to log Spring 5 WebClient call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154994/how-to-log-spring-5-webclient-call)

Answer (score 0):

Try Custom Logger:

```
CustomLogger logger = new CustomLogger(TcpClient.class);         
TcpClient tcpClient = TcpClient.create().doOnRequest((request, connection) -> 
    {
     connection.addHandlerFirst(logger);
    });
```